# Efficient greedy algorithm for elements with distances.

Tags: algorithms

Let's say we have n points on a line all sorted by distance from an origin. There are only points on the right side of the origin. We want to make the biggest subset of these points as long as no two points are ever closer than ε. How would we go about this?

My intuition is to always pick the first dot then check if the next dot is more than ε and and recursively do this again once we add a new dot. Is this right?

If so, how do I prove that this is an efficient greedy algorithm?

Comment: What do you mean by 'they are sorted by distance'? Do they have a distance from a fixed point (for example, the origin)? It's not clear where these points live. Are they vertices of a graph, or something?

Comment: @Crostul clarified sorry

Answer (score 1):

Number the points $1$ through $n$.  Any set that does not include point $1$ can be matched up with one that has the same number of points, but substitutes point $1$ for the first point, so taking point $1$ cannot hurt.

Answer (score 1):

Using the approach of Ross Millikan you can show that this is a correct algorithm via induction.

Let $I$ be the index set of points that your greedy algorithm chooses and $J$ the index set of an optimal solution. As Ross Millikan pointed out, taking point 1 for the first point in $J$ does not change the number of points in $J$ and $J$ is still feasible. Now assume that the first $k-1$ indices in $I$ and $J$ are identical. Since the $k$-th index in $I$ is the first possible point after the $(k-1)$-th index in $I$ (and $J$), we can replace the $k$-th index in $J$ by the $k$-th index in $I$. Again, the number of points in $J$ will not change and $J$ will still be feasible.

Using this induction, the optimal solution $J$ is step by step transformed to the solution $I$ of your algorithm.